# Programmatically set edited cell on Spark Datagrid

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, actionscript, flex-spark

What is the equivalent of editedItemPosition for the Spark datagrid?

Answer (score 3):

To programmatically set the editing cell

```
dataGrid.startItemEditorSession(rowIndex, columnIndex)
```

To retrieve the editing cell

```
dataGrid.editorColumnIndex
dataGrid.editorRowIndex
```

More details: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS0ab2a460655f2dc3-427f401412c60d04dca-7ff3.html

Answer (score -1):

Try these properties :

```
editorColumnIndex="0"
editorRowIndex="0"
```

Comment: He didn't specify that he needed to set the property (it is just a one sentence question) - had he clarified he needed that then a new solution could be suggested.